# If using "ActiveLabel.swift" to tag words have space, it'll fail to tag - swift

Tags: ios, swift, label, uilabel

I have a question to tag person's name using ActiveLabel.swift.
But I face a problem.
If person's name have space, it will fail to tag all name with space.
What's wrong with me?
Have any good idea to me?
Thanks.

```
myLabel.customize { (label) in

        label.text = "@Kevin k Hello"

        label.handleMentionTap({ (mentionString) in //mentionString = Kevin
            guard self.tagsLabelDic[mentionString] != nil else { return } // self.tagsLabelDic = ["Kevin k": "appname://app/user/aa445cfaef786864044f12e2"]
            guard let url = URL(string: self.tagsLabelDic[mentionString]!) else { return }
            self.taggedDelegate?.tagsLabelClicked(url: url)
        })
}
```

[image: test]

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to use a custom type

Something like this:

`let customType = ActiveType.custom(pattern: "\\s@Kevin\\sk\\sHello")`

Comment: Hey @Vyacheslav, how does the `RegularExpression` pattern works, I am pulling my hairs out but not able to understand.

Comment: @iPeter In breaf, RegularExpression is a rule to find some substring which corresponds to the desired pattern. For instance, '[a-z]+' regex says: i will find all substrings with lowercase chars , all strings will have lenght more or equal then 1 charactrer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. If you can give me some links from where I can learn `regx` then it will be a great help to me. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks a billion times. :)